# how to export data to a CSV file in ODI 12c

Tags: export-to-csv, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

I have a table in DB which I need to export the data based on the *condition < current date* to a **CSV** file using **ODI 12c** can I get the steps please..

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to export data from DB to a file using a condition.

1) Create a New Package

2) Under Toolbox navigate to Files --> click on OdiSqlUnload and click on the actual package area.

3) Input Parameters in Properties section

```
 Target File: Give the Path where file needs to be created
 JDBC Driver: Oracle.jdbc.oracledriver
 JDBC URL: Give the jdbc url which you use to connect to DB
 User: User Name for the DB which you are trying to connect to.
 Pwd:
 File Format: Delimited
 Field Separator: , (Comma)
 SQL Query: Example: select * from emp where rownum<10
```

4) Leave the rest all parameters as is

5) Save Package and execute the step with desired context. If you are creating file in local do not use agent while execution.